# Testing Socket.io: Running assertions after calling Socket.prototype.disconnect

Tags: javascript, socket.io, jestjs

## Problem

**Note: This is a contrived example for demonstration purposes and is not the actual code I am testing in my project.**

I am writing tests for my [Socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/) server using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/).

I want to test that a particular function (`MyController.prototype.disconnect`) is called after a socket disconnects.

This is the code I want to test:

```js
const handleDisconnect = () => {
    myController.disconnect(); // I want to test that this is called.
    console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} has disconnected.`);
};
socket.on('disconnect', handleDisconnect);
```

However, I cannot figure out how to wait for the execution of `Socket.prototype.disconnect` to finish before writing my assertions (it is not asynchronous).

## Reproducing the Problem

1. Install the dependencies:

```
"jest": "^24.8.0",
"socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"
"socket.io": "^2.2.0"
```

2. Create a file named `demo.test.js` and paste in the following code.

```js
const ioClient = require('socket.io-client');
const ioServer = require('socket.io');

class MyController {

    constructor() {}

    disconnect() {
        console.log('MyController.prototype.disconnect');
    }

}

describe('demo', () => {

    let port = 5000, 
        uri = `http://localhost:${port}`,
        connectOptions = {
            'reconnection delay': 0,
            'reopen delay': 0,
            'force new connection': true,
            transports: ['websocket']
        };

    let server;
    let myController;

    beforeEach(() => {
        server = ioServer().listen(port);

        server.on('connection', (socket) => {
            console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} has connected.`);

            myController = new MyController();

            const handleDisconnect = () => {
                myController.disconnect();
                console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} has disconnected.`);
            };

            socket.on('disconnect', handleDisconnect);
        });

    });

    afterEach((done) => {
        server.close();
        done();
    });

    const createClient = () => {
        return ioClient.connect(uri, connectOptions);
    }

    describe('handleDisconnect', () => {

        test.only('Should call MyController.prototype.disconnect when a socket disconnects', (done) => {
            const client = createClient();

            client.on('connect', () => {

                // Mock MyController.prototype.disconnect to see if it was called
                const myControllerDisconnectMock = jest.fn();
                myController.disconnect = myControllerDisconnectMock;

                client.disconnect(); // I want to wait for this

                /**
                 * I want to put assertions here after client.disconnect() runs
                 */
                console.log('foo'); // But notice this runs before client.disconnect()

                expect(myControllerDisconnectMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
                done();
            });
        });

    });

});
```

3. Run the tests:

```
jest demo.test.js
```

Console output (simplified for brevity):

`'MyController.prototype.disconnect'` is not logged because that prototype method is mocked.

```
Expected: 1
Received: 0
  console.log demo.test.js:32
    Socket OKkN21L8dBzzrRiuAAAA has connected.

  console.log demo.test.js:72
    foo

  console.log demo.test.js:38
    Socket OKkN21L8dBzzrRiuAAAA has disconnected.
```

Comment: Call the disconnect function in the controller directly with.... and pass the necessary parameters you know socket.io will pass

dont bother test socket.io disconnect... just imagine your controller disconnect function is called